# How to mock lodash's throttle function in jest?

Tags: javascript, lodash, throttling

I came across functionality where we're using lodash's throttle to avoid unnecessary function calls like below.

```
export const helperFn = throttle((args) => console.log(args), 1000)
```

I want to mock the throttle function of lodash. what is the best way to mock throttled fn.

Comment: How are you importing `throttle` in the piece of code that you want to test?

Comment: import throttle from 'lodash/throttle'

Comment: @RahulBhobe I'm using throttle from lodash.

Answer (score 1):

This has gone a while without an answer, so you probably have a solution by now. But for those who come along later, a viable solution would be to use jests `mock` function to make throttle simply return the passed in method. For example:

```
jest.mock("lodash/throttle", () => {
  return fn => fn;
});
```